ASP.NET Core Web API : serializing Json to string
I have an ASP.NET Core Web API which I am using as a proxy to another third party API. I have a few endpoints which I have a controller for, but I also act as a proxy to the third-party API for all other requests that are sent to me which I don't have a custom endpoint for. I essentially forward on those request to the third-party API.
I have some custom middleware to handle the incoming requests. If I have a custom endpoint for the request I call _next.Invoke. If I don't, I forward the request to the third-party API.
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (IsCustomEnpoint(context))
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
        else 
        {
            await ForwardRequest(context);
        }
        return;
    }

When I call ForwardRequest, I use a HttpClient to send the request and get back some JSON as a string and use the following method to modify the HttpContext:
private static async Task ModifyResponse(HttpContext context, string json)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(json));
}

Doing this adds extra quotation marks around the json, so the original requestor receives:
"{
  "name": "Bob Boberty",
}"

Instead of
{
  "name": "Bob Boberty",
}

From my understanding this is because the Web API is taking responsibility of the serialization and serializing the string. I know how to get round this on the client side code by first deserializing to a string and then deserializing to the desired object but that seems like a bit of a bodge.
Is there a way to stop this from happening? All the examples I've seen of solving this has not been suitable in this scenario.

Just write the string directly

you can directly write the raw JSON string to the response body without further serialization. Here’s how you can modify your ModifyResponse method to avoid double serialization
private static async Task ModifyResponse(HttpContext context, string json)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

    // Convert the raw JSON string to bytes and write it to the response
    var jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
    await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(jsonBytes, 0, jsonBytes.Length);
}

output should then be
{
  "name": "Bob Boberty"
}


This is because internally JsonSerializer is used on whatever you write to response body. And when string is serialized, then it gets extra pair of " around it:
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize("str"); // -> result in "\"str\""

To avoid it, you need to write raw bytes in your method instead, to let know underlying system, to not do another serializetion, so change this
await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(json));

to this
await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));

